# Galleriffic next page load first image issue

Tags: jquery, galleriffic

I'm using galleriffic for my page, the problem is every-time i click the thumbnail next page, the big image change to next page first image.

This is the [example](http://www.twospy.com/galleriffic/example-5.html#leaf) from galleriffic itself.

Everytime i click the next page it's change, How to have focus at the image that i clicked?

I tried searching at google and changing the jquery but without any success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my own way to fix that problem..

I delete the next prev function from the galleriffic
and i combine it with jcarousellite

so my next and prev function is handle by jcarousellite

Comment: Hey can you share how you did this?? I am having the same issue, which I click next page, I see the  First or Last thumbnail of "previous page"